# Полнотекстовый поиск MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, полнотекстовый-поиск

Как настроить поиск, чтобы можно было искать по подстроке. Точнее по началу слова. Например:

```
> db.orders.insert({"name":"О введении журнала регистрации посетителей"})
> db.orders.ensureIndex({name: "text"}, {default_language: "russian"})

> db.orders.find({$text: {$search: "посетит"}})
```

Поиск ничего не находит. 
Возможно ли вообще такое сделать средствами полнотекстового поиска mongo?